# Rename Symbol (F2) returns "No result."

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

When I try to refactor variables using the Rename Symbol action, the variable is not refactored, and a tooltip pops up that says "No result." There are no error messages, or any other indication that something is wrong.

VS Code was recently updated to ver 1.56.1, and along with this update came a switch to Pylance. Before this update, Rename Symbol worked, but now it doesn't work on Remote-SSH, Remote-WSL, or local workspaces. On Remote-WSL in particular, pressing F2 will not even display the refactor dialogue box.

I have tried restarting the Python Language Server, restarting VS Code, and restarting my PC, but nothing has worked. I would like to continue using Pylance if possible.

Comment: I've been having the same problem, i think its a bug in the new update.

Comment: Is there any differences after reinstalling python and pylance extension? If not, please post the version number you currently use,

Answer (score 1):

With the new update (1.56.2), the problem had been fixed.